# Spring batch How to write an XML file with header and footer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am able to read the data from DB and write an XML using StaxEventItemWriter with root tag. How to add an header and footer to the XML file?

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
    ItemWriter<BatchRequest> databaseXmlItemWriter() {
        StaxEventItemWriter<BatchRequest> xmlFileWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();        

        xmlFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(System.getProperty("outputFile")));
        xmlFileWriter.setRootTagName("employee");

        Jaxb2Marshaller employeeMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        employeeMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(BatchRequest.class);
        xmlFileWriter.setMarshaller(employeeMarshaller);
        return xmlFileWriter;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter#setHeaderCallback` and `org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter#setFooterCallback` to write a header/footer to the XML file with a `org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxWriterCallback`.

Comment: can I have more details or link for examples please.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mahmoud said in his answer that we can use `StaxEventItemWriter's` `setHeaderCallback()` and `setFooterCallback()` to register our header and footer code.

**Below is a code snippet for you:**

```
@StepScope
@Bean(name = "staxTransactionWriter")
public StaxEventItemWriter<BatchRequest> staxTransactionItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['file.path']}") String path) {
    Resource exportFileResource = new FileSystemResource(path);

    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(BatchRequest.class);
    
     StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<BatchRequest> writer = new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<BatchRequest>();
     writer.setName("employeeWriter");
     writer.setVersion("1.0");
     writer.setResource(exportFileResource);
     writer.setMarshaller(marshaller);
     writer.setRootTagName("employee");
     writer.setHeaderCallback(getXmlHeaderCallBack());
     writer.setFooterCallback(getXmlFooterCallBack());
     writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
     return writer;
}

@Bean
OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack getXmlHeaderCallBack(){
    return new XmlHeaderCallBack();
}

@Bean
OmegaXmlFooterCallBack getXmlFooterCallBack(){
    return new XmlFooterCallBack();
}
```

**Below code creates a custom header and footer classes which extends StaxWriterCallback:**

```
@Slf4j
public class XmlFooterCallBack implements StaxWriterCallback {

    @Override
    public void write(XMLEventWriter writer) {
        XMLEventFactory factory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "record"));
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            log.error("Error writing OMEGA XML Footer: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new OmegaXmlHeaderWriterException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Slf4j
public class XmlHeaderCallBack implements StaxWriterCallback {
    
    public XmlHeaderCallBack() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(XMLEventWriter writer) {
        XMLEventFactory factory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "fileInformation"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "sender"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters("SENDER ID"));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "sender"));


            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "timestamp"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters("CURRENT DATE_TIME"));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "timestamp"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "environment"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters("LOCAL"));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "environment"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "version"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters("1.2.3"));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "version"));
            
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "fileInformation"));
            
            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "record"));
            
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            log.error("Error writing XML Header: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new CustomXmlHeaderWriterException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

> Header will look like

```
    <fileInformation>
      <sender>SENDER ID</sender>
      <timestamp>CURRENT DATE_TIME</timestamp>
      <environment>LOCAL</environment>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
   </fileInformation>
   <record>
```

> Footer will have the closing tag of `record`

```
</record>
```